# Order fields in UNION query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union

I am trying to make an union query in MySQL between two queries.  But, each query is ordered by a different field, and I need both queries in only one query.  Is that possible?

For example, I have this table:

```
table

------
A | B
------
1 | 3
------
2 | 2
------
3 | 1
```

I have tried with this query:

```
(SELECT A, B)
    FROM table 
    ORDER BY A)
UNION
(SELECT A, B)
    FROM table 
    ORDER BY B)
```

And I want to get something like this:

```
A | B
------
1 | 3
------
2 | 2
------
3 | 1
------
3 | 1
------
2 | 2
------
1 | 3
```

But, instead of that, I get the union of both queries without ordering, like this:

```
A | B
------
1 | 3
------
2 | 2
------
3 | 1
------
1 | 3
------
2 | 2
------
3 | 1
```

How must I do it?  Of course, if I do both queries separately, it works, but I need them in the same query.

Comment: Once a question is answered satisfactorily, it's helpful to accept that answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce an extra column which tracks each side of the union, and then use it order as you want.

```
SELECT t.A, t.B
FROM
(
    SELECT A, B, 'A' AS source
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A, B, 'B'
    FROM yourTable
) t
ORDER BY
    t.source,
    CASE WHEN t.source = 'A' THEN A ELSE B END
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester